# How to change next default value for PostgreSQL sequence?

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-sequence

I have a table where the ID sequence goes like 01,02 and so on (I have a few pre-inserted values). When I try to insert a new row there (not specifying the ID explicitly, but rather values for other columns) it tells me that the default value is "1" which is the same as "01" and can't be inserted. How to fix it, thank you!

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/sql-createsequence.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use START WITH argument while creating the sequence.

Example:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE sequenceName
    START WITH 1  
    INCREMENT BY 1 ;
```

For more documentation go through the [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-sequence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)